# Linq how to map collections to object from multiple result sets

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How to map collections to object from multiple result sets with Linq

I am trying to map collections to their object but i get wrong result

My business object looks like this

```
public class ProductForAjax
{
    public ProductForAjax()
    {
        this.DynamicProperties = new List<DynamicProperty>();
        this.Categories = new List<Category>();
    }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DynamicProperty> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class DynamicProperty
{
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the way i tried to map the collections to the object

```
var See = db.Database.SqlQuery<GetProduct>("EXEC sp_GetProduct @ProductId", par).ToList();

var grouped = (from c in See
                   group new
                   {
                       c.PropertyId,
                       c.PropertyName,
                       c.PropertyValue,
                       c.SubCategoryId,
                       c.SubCategoryName
                   }
                   by new
                   {
                       c.ProductId,
                       c.ProductName,
                       c.ProductPrice,
                       c.ProductQuantity
                   }).ToList();


ProductForAjax J = grouped.Select(c => new ProductForAjax()
    {
        ProductId = c.Key.ProductId,
        ProductName = c.Key.ProductName,
        ProductPrice = c.Key.ProductPrice,
        ProductQuantity = c.Key.ProductQuantity,
        DynamicProperties = c.Select(x => new DynamicProperty()
        {
            PropertyId = x.PropertyId,
            PropertyName = x.PropertyName,
            PropertyValue = x.PropertyValue
        }
        ).ToList(),
        Categories = c.Select(y => new Category()
            {
                CategoryId = y.SubCategoryId,
                CategoryName = y.SubCategoryName
            }).ToList()
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am actually new to Linq so please don't solve my problem based on my code because i don't know if it's right or not. So Please tell me how such a case solved in real-world

Comment: you need to add more text with simple words. what do u mean by `mapping` to object?

Comment: Thank you  Alex, i will to fill the public IEnumerable<DynamicProperty> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; } with values from the result